# Split Large CSV into multiple files by column

Tags: linux, file, csv, awk, split

I have a CSV that is 4.5GB in size. I would like to separate this CSV into different files based on columns. For example:

```
File1.csv: Cols(1,35,36,37)    
File2.csv: Cols(1,127,129,135) 
File3.csv: Cols(1,285,287,299,311) 
File4.csv: Cols(1,2,4,5,6,12,13,14)
```

** note column 1 is an id column and is needed throughout.

Essentially I want to break up this CSV that contains 328 columns into what will be many smaller CSV's for Mysql import.

While I could easily do this with multiple awk commands I do not want to re-process an entire 4.5GB-6GB file with each command. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [redirect output](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) of `print` to different files within awk:

```
awk '{print $1, $35, $36, $37 > "file1.csv"} \
     {print $1, $127, $129, $135 > "file2.csv"} \
     {print $1, $285, $287, $299, $311 > "file3.csv"}\
     {print $1, $2, $4, $5, $6, $12, $13, $14 > "file4.csv"}' inFile.csv
```

Comment: This unfortunately throws an error:

awk: 1: unexpected character '.'

Comment: @Mrd05d: You are supposed to replace the `...` with the `print` commands for the other two files.

Comment: Oh... yea sorry about that @Mrd05d  I was lazy and didn't feel like typing anymore. Figured you'd get the gist of awk redirects and take it from there.  :)

Comment: I get the error even with just one: awk -F',' '{print $1,$2,$3 > file1.csv}' filein.csv

Comment: Just made another update wrapping the filenames in double quotes. Helps to read the manual, I suppose. give this one a shot.